# python docker apis how to create a user and group inside the container

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

how do we create a user inside a container using python docker apis?
I am just running this but I am having errors to write to the home directory of the user. I am getting permission errors....

```
contCIS = cli.runContainer(buildImage, './MysqlScript.sh',
                                                network='bridgecontainers',
                                                volumes={os.getcwd(): {'bind': '/Build/', 'mode': 'rw'}, '/Users/rg/.m2/': {'bind': '/tmp/.m2/', 'mode': 'rw'}}, user=501, detach=True)
```

I am seeing errors like this below

```
linux spec user: unable to find user jenkins: no matching entries in passwd file
```

or is there a way to mount current user into container on a mac host ?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question

Comment: The Docker APIs don't have any way to create users or otherwise change the filesystem inside containers before they start.  I think the usual solutions involve an entrypoint script that gets the host user identity passed as a parameter.  Given how much you're having to work around Docker's core design in this setup, also consider just using the `subprocess` module to run your build tool and leaving Docker out of it.

Comment: or is there a way to mount current user into container on a mac host ?